# Loading data with gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I was trying to set up very simply GUI with R consisting of a single button which I use to load RData into the Workspace.

The Code Looks like this:

```
rm(list = ls()) # clean workspace
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetstcltk)
source("loadData.R")
options("guiToolkit"="tcltk")
win=gwindow("Analysis", visible = TRUE)
group = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container=win)
obj=gbutton("Load data", container = group,  handler = loadData   ("dataXML_saved.RData"))
```

When I source, I get the Window as desired eventually.
However, when I push the "load data" button again, I get the following 
error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function

The function to load data data Looks like this:

```
loadData = function(file){
load(file, .GlobalEnv)    
}
```

For some reason, the handler of gbutton does not accept the load function. So this why I embedded it within the loadData function.

Any idea what the Problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an anonymous function. You seem to be passing an expression as a handler.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly what you mentioned. 
So this is what I tried to implement eventually, however did not succeed:

```
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetstcltk)

w <- gwindow("Button examples")
g <- ggroup(container = w)
addSpring(g) ## push to right of widget
gbutton("help", container = g)
addSpace(g, 20) ## some breathing room
gbutton("cancel", container = g)
gbutton("ok", container = g, handler = lapply("dataXML_saved.RData",     function(x) load(x)))
```

I get the same error message as before though.

Comment: You need handler=function(h,...) {.......}. Where you put your commands between the braces.